# Slicing a string and sets it to a label and now the label is not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to slice a string and now my label wont show..

First I got a DoubleVar with a default float value. Then I'm trying to convert the updated value to a string and then slice it and set the value to the label, whitch result come from an entry and OptionsMenu.

The thing I'm tryng to achieve is to always get a value in the resultlabel1 with 3 decimals, that updates when the entry and OptionsMenu changes.

The code I'm speaking about:

```
self.resultlabel1 = DoubleVar()
self.resultlabel1.set(float(0.000))

self.label1 = Label(root, textvariable=str(self.resultlabel1)[:5])
self.label1.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
```

My total code is here:

```
from tkinter import *
from decimal import *

class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.materialPrice = {'Brick': 70, 'Rockwool': 50, 'Concrete': 20}

        materialvariable1 = StringVar(self, root)
        materialvariable1.set("Choose material")
        materialvariable2 = StringVar(self, root)
        materialvariable2.set("Choose materiale")

        self.w1 = OptionMenu(root, materialvariable1, *self.materialPrice, command=self.displayPrice)
        self.w1.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        self.w2 = OptionMenu(root, materialvariable2, *self.materialPrice, command=self.displayPrice2)
        self.w2.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.var = DoubleVar()
        self.var.set(Decimal("0.100"))
        self.var2 = DoubleVar()
        self.var2.set(Decimal("0.200"))

        self.entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var)
        self.entry1.grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=self.var2)
        self.entry2.grid(row=3, column=1)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.priceVarLabel1 = DoubleVar()
        self.priceVarLabel1.set(float(0.00))
        self.priceVarLabel2 = DoubleVar()
        self.priceVarLabel2.set(float(0.00))

        self.priceVarValue1 = Label(root, textvariable=self.priceVarLabel1, relief='sunken')
        self.priceVarValue1.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
        self.priceVarValue2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.priceVarLabel2, relief='sunken')
        self.priceVarValue2.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        self.resultlabel1 = DoubleVar()
        self.resultlabel1.set(float(0.000))
        self.resultlabel2 = DoubleVar()
        self.resultlabel2.set(float(0.00))

# This is what I got so far!
        self.label1 = Label(root, textvariable=str(self.resultlabel1)[:5])
        self.label1.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        self.label2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.resultlabel2)
        self.label2.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.resultSumNew = DoubleVar()
        #self.resultSumNew.set(float(0.00))
        self.resultSumNew.set(Decimal("0.000"))
        self.labelSum = Label(root, textvariable=self.resultSumNew)
        self.labelSum.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

        def set_label(name, index, mode):
            self.resultSumNew.set(self.var.get() + self.var2.get())

        self.var.trace('w', set_label)
        self.var2.trace('w', set_label)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def displayPrice(self, value):
        self.resultlabel1.set(self.var.get() / self.materialPrice[value])
        self.priceVarLabel1.set(self.materialPrice[value])                                                              

    def displayPrice2(self, value):
        self.resultlabel2.set(self.var2.get() / self.materialPrice[value])
        self.priceVarLabel2.set(self.materialPrice[value])



root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.title("help")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it this way. Used `StringVar` for Label text and then sliced it accordingly

```
self.resultlabel1 = DoubleVar()
self.resultlabel1.set(float(0.000))
self.resultlabel2 = DoubleVar()
self.resultlabel2.set(float(0.00))

self.resultlabel1_str = StringVar()
self.resultlabel1_str.set(str(self.resultlabel1.get()))

self.label1 = Label(root, textvariable=self.resultlabel1_str)
self.label1.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')

self.label2 = Label(root, textvariable=self.resultlabel2)
self.label2.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky='WE')
```

And in your functions,

```
def displayPrice(self, value):
    self.resultlabel1.set(self.var.get() / self.materialPrice[value])
    self.priceVarLabel1.set(self.materialPrice[value])   
    self.resultlabel1_str.set(str(self.resultlabel1.get())[:5])                                                           

def displayPrice2(self, value):
    self.resultlabel2.set(self.var2.get() / self.materialPrice[value])
    self.priceVarLabel2.set(self.materialPrice[value])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works perfectly! Exatly what i needed! Thank you very mutch! :)